# How to fix Sidenav showing in Chrome but not Safari - (Angular 7/Bootstrap project)

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

My side-nav appears and functions perfectly in Chrome but not in Safari. Trying to find the code that is making it  break. Here are some photos that show the two side-navs. Chrome is the one that works and Safari is the blank one.

[image]
[image]

I've already tried going into dev tools on both Safari and Chrome to check if any CSS styling attributes have been crossed out but they all seem to be there.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav custom-underline">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="nav-items">
      <a href="#/home">Home</a>
      <a href="#/videos">Videos</a>
      <a href="#/art">Art</a>
      <a href="#/graphic-design">Graphic Design</a>
      <a href="#/contact">Contact</a>

      <a href="http://instagram.com/*****" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
    .nav-items a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(214, 0, 0);
}

i{
    color: white;
}


/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-logo{
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

}

.closebtn{
    margin-top: 8px;

}

#video-icon{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position: relative;
    top:9px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 200px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
    .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Comment: Is this an Angular project? If yes why there is onclick? Could you make a demo on stackblitz?

Comment: The onClick is to trigger the javascript to pop the menu out. Yeah I'll make a stackblitz demo for you to check out. I don't know if the bug will happen on stack blitz though. Actually if you go to the website www.roycreates.com you can test it out through the inspector on there

Comment: I know what  onclick is for ;) What I don't know is why would you use it while your project is Angular. I bet that's the issue. Change it to (click) and if not yet, refactor the function to make it a class method

Comment: I tried importing angular material sidenav and running only that component. Nothing shows up in the <mat-nav-list> I got rid of all the javascript and it's still bugging out. Not too sure what the issue is..

Comment: Were you able to make a stackblitz example? You can fork from AM site examples and add your code on top of it